# how to append check box CommandName and CommandArgument in asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

i just want to append command name and command argument to check box so repeater item command get fired from check box at run time. here is my design code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_Category" runat="server" onitemcommand="Repeater_Category_ItemCommand">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CategoryName")%>' AutoPostBack="true" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>'/>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdValue" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                      <SeparatorTemplate>&nbsp;&nbsp;</SeparatorTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                        <Triggers>
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Repeater_Category" 
                                                EventName="ItemCommand" />
                                        </Triggers>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

here is my Repeater Item Command Event code :

```
 protected void Repeater_Category_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Select"))
        {
            List<int?> GroupByCategory = null;
            if (e.CommandArgument.Equals("-1"))
            {
                GroupByCategory.Clear();
                Session["GroupByCategory"] = null;
                this.FillGrid((String)Session["GroupByText"] ?? null, (List<int?>)Session["GroupByCategory"] ?? null, (List<int?>)Session["GroupByStatus"] ?? null, (String)Session["ColumnName"] ?? null, (String)Session["SearchText"] ?? null);
            }
            else
            {
                GroupByCategory.Add(int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
                Session["GroupByCategory"] = GroupByCategory;
                this.FillGrid((String)Session["GroupByText"] ?? null,(List<int?>)Session["GroupByCategory"] ?? null,(List<int?>)Session["GroupByStatus"] ?? null,(String)Session["ColumnName"] ?? null, (String)Session["SearchText"] ?? null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: at debugging to this event cursor didn't call so i think command name and command argument doesn't working with check box

Comment: the CheckBox doesn't have such properties. You could add a CheckedChanged event though, with AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar just read this [article](http://www.frankwisniewski.net/2013/01/how-to-make-a-checkbox-fire-the-itemcommand-event-of-a-repeater/)

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar can u explain with code.

Comment: did you read at last...... As you can tell, in the OnCheckChanged event we are calling “base.RaiseBubbleEvent”.....he is calling OncheckChanged event